# Automatic sorting and compression of a range of numeric-style citation call-outs

Tags: bibtex, citing, cite-package

Hi All I want to display the following citation call-outs as `[1-10]` instead of `[1-3,3-4,4-7,7-10]`.

I use the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=0.3in, right=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[noadjust,compress]{cite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}

\cite{xin2011multitaper,wang2009multitaper,al2010multitaper,%
    al2010multitaper,jataprolu2012optimal,chiang2009optimal,%
    yousif2014new,jataprolu2012optimal}

\bibliography{Ref}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Your question may receive more attention if you provide a `bib` file that makes use of your citation keys, and if you strip off all unnecessary packages. I'm also struggling to understand why you call `\bibliographystyle` twice.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I added \bibliographystyle as I though it is necessary to exhibit the differences in a certain style

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is that two of the entry keys in the `\cite` instruction are repeated. Eliminate the repeats, and you'll immediately obtain the desired format of the sorted citation call-outs.

By the way, since there are only 6 distinct entry keys in your `\cite` instruction, the most you can get is `[1-6]`, *not* `[1-10]`.

Separately, do also make up your mind whether you want to employ the `unsrt` or the `plain` bibliography style. (You should have gotten a warning message about this during the BibTeX run.) There can be only one bibliography style in effect in your sample document.

A full MWE (note that I've eliminated all unnecessary instructions from the preamble):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Ref.bib}
@misc{xin2011multitaper,   author={X}, title={AA}, year=3001} 
@misc{wang2009multitaper,  author={W}, title={BB}, year=3002} 
@misc{al2010multitaper,    author={A}, title={CC}, year=3003} 
@misc{jataprolu2012optimal,author={J}, title={DD}, year=3004} 
@misc{chiang2009optimal,   author={C}, title={EE}, year=3005} 
@misc{yousif2014new,       author={Y}, title={FF}, year=3006} 
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in,hmargin=0.3in]{geometry}

\usepackage[noadjust]{cite} % 'sort' and 'compress' are enabled by default
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}% or: \bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

bad: \cite{xin2011multitaper,wang2009multitaper,al2010multitaper,%
        al2010multitaper,jataprolu2012optimal,chiang2009optimal,%
        yousif2014new,jataprolu2012optimal}

good: \cite{xin2011multitaper,wang2009multitaper,
         al2010multitaper,jataprolu2012optimal,
         chiang2009optimal,yousif2014new}

\bibliography{Ref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it is a big help . I 'm wondering about your data base items                                                                                                                                                
\begin{filecontents}{Ref.bib}
@misc{xin2011multitaper,   author={X}, title={AA}, year=3001} 
\end{filecontents}

Comment: I use bibtex style form google scholar  in separate file called Ref.bib             and i wrote as follow                                                                                   @article{childers1977cepstrum,
 title={The cepstrum: A guide to processing},
 author={Childers, Donald G and Skinner, David P and Kemerait, Robert C},
 journal={Proceedings of the IEEE},
 volume={65},
 number={10},
 pages={1428--1443},
 year={1977},
 publisher={IEEE}
}

Comment: @hobeyomar - You wrote, "I 'm wondering about your data base items". Those are obviously made up out of thin air. All I was trying to do is to create dummy entries that could be called in `\cite` instructions. (If you want to provide the actual, real entries, feel free to do so by editing your original query.) The point I made in the answer stands, though: How do you expect to create a citation call-out of the form `[1-10]` if only 6 distinct entries are being cited? Please advise.

Comment: I don't argue bout "How do you expect to create a citation call-out of the form [1-10] if only 6 distinct entries are being cited?" you are true , I just repeat them as a mistake .                                                            but I just 've asked about your entry data base as I noticed from that one I followed

Comment: @hobeyomar - I'm afraid I didn't understand what you're trying to say in your comment. Very sorry.